# HTML change input file styling bind function

Tags: html, file, vue.js, input

Here is my file input;

```
<input type="file" id="restoreFile">
```

The first thing I want to do is to change its styling properties. First I added `display: none;` and I created a label for my "restoreFile" input, I did the styling for the Label and designed it as a button so it looks okay. After I press the label (button) the functionality of the file input is working, but because of I added `display: none;` for file input, I don't see the file name when I choose one.

A little extra;
I also want another button to be appear after I select a file from file input. I am working on Vuejs project so here it looks;

```
 <input type="file" id="restoreFile" @click="showRestore=true">
```

I have a data and it is set to false by default. And there is the button that I want it to be shown after I select a file from file input.

```
<button type="button" v-show="showRestore">Restore</button>
```

In this situation, showRestore variable is converted to `true` right after I clicked the input file, but I want it to be turned to true right after I select a file. I just don't want to see the Restore button without browsing a file from pc. It does not make any sense. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually get the selected file details in javascript

in your HTML;

```
<label><input type="file" id="restoreFile" ref="fileselect" @change="getFileInfo()"/></label>

<!--display the filename -->
<p>{{filename}}</p>
```

In Jour Javascript

```
data: {
   filename: 'No file selected'
   
  },
  methods:{
  getFileInfo(){
   this.filename =this.$refs["fileselect"].files[0].name
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim, the solution really helped me. But I still couldn't figure out the second part of the question. I couldn't find any solution for showing restore button after the file selection.

Comment: set the ```showRestore```  to ```true``` inside the ```getFileInfo()``` function. That way it will only be true after a file has been chosen